# How to do curd operation in Hbase using Apache MetaModel?

Tags: hbase, apache-metamodel

I want to insert data in Hbase database using apache MetaModel. I have got the HbaseConfiguration object using host and port number. After that, how to insert data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, MetaModel does not implement write capabilities for HBase at the moment. Only querying the data is possible.

Comment: But datacontext does not have executeupdate method. Updatabledatacontext has this method.

Comment: My bad. HBaseDataContext does not implement UpdateableDataContext, which means you can use HBase via MetaModel only in read-only mode. I should edit my original answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider marking the answer as correct.

Comment: I am facing some issues in case of select operation.using metamodel api ,i can only able to fetch columns name not values or some values that is not understandable .But i want to fetch column + cell values that i can understand .Can u help..

Comment: HBase saves data in a binary form, so that not understandable data is just a steam of bytes. Try converting these bytes to the type that you expect for given column.